# Importing .csv files with Sys.Dates()

Tags: r, date, import

I have a .csv dataset that gets dumped everyday which I use to generate a daily list for tracking participants using a R script. I would like to automate this R script, however in order to do so, I need to read in the .csv using Sys.Date().

The .csv dataset is named: DumpedList_2013-11-27 (The date will always be today's date).

I would like to import this into the script, like I would for .Rdata file. 
`load(paste('/srv/Data/Baseline2/baseline2_', Sys.Date(), '.Rdata',sep=''))`

What is the equivalent of the command above for reading in .csv files?

I have tried load and read.csv commands, but get error messages:
`data=read.csv('P:/DirectoryPath/DumpedList_',Sys.Date(),'.csv')`

I also attempted to create `todaydate=Sys.Date()` and then used it to load the data, but error messages again. `a=load(paste("P:/DirectoryPath/DumpedList_",todaydate,".csv"))`

Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `paste` will separate with spaces, use `paste0` to join strings together seamlessly:

```
read.csv(paste0('P:/DirectoryPath/DumpedList_',Sys.Date(),'.csv'))
```